# list problem in my javascript todo list exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, for-loop

I've checked many times but since I'm new I'm constantly missing something. In the console, my list is does not appear as [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tLou.jpg)....and my output is like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeRGQ.jpg)

Everything is correct, but is there something I don't know about the console?

```
let input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
const todos= ['list app finish', 'js practice'];
while (input !== 'quit' && input !=="go away aysel"){ 
    if(input === 'list') {
        console.log('***********')
        for (let num = 0; num< todos.length; i++){
            console.log("${num} ${todos[num]}");
        }
        console.log('*************')
    }
    input= prompt('What would you like to do')
}
console.log('Good bye')
```

Answer (score 1):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) work with the backtick char  `` ` ``.
They do **not** work with string quotes like `'` and `"`

so you need to change the logging to

```js
console.log(`${num} ${todos[num]}`);
```

Comment: thank you for answer,I can sleep comfortably now...You are hero